# No reference to project item created through AddFromTemplate() returned 

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in, envdte, projectitem

In a Visual Studio Add-In that successfully creates a form, but gives me no reference back to the EnvDTE's prjItem instance.

Here's the piece of code that adds the form to the project:

```
string templatePath = solution.GetProjectItemTemplate("Form.zip", "csproj");
ProjectItem prjItem = project.ProjectItems.AddFromTemplate(templatePath, "myForm.cs");
```

Obs.: 'solution' is an EnvDTE80.Solution2 object.

Of cource I can get the reference by other ways, like proj.ProjectItems.Item([index]) (doing a loop and checking for names), but that's not how I want to do it, and I need this reference in orther to add controls to this form.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just wrote a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185370/adding-controls-to-a-form-when-i-only-have-the-reference-to-its-envdte

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just found a comment on MSDN:

> AddFromTemplate always returns a NULL
> value
>
> At one time, this was true. But
> with later versions of Visual Studio,
> which included the ability to add
> multiple items from a single template,
> the return value for this method could
> not return multiple items. So it now
> returns a NULL value in all instances.
> This is due to the contraint that the
> COM signature for this particular
> method cannot be changed without
> breaking a lot of code already in use.
>
> Consequently, if you need the
> ProjectItem interface of the item just
> added via the AddFromTemplate call,
> you can either iterate through the
> ProjectItems collection, or you can
> create a ProjectItemsEvents.ItemAdded
> event just before calling
> AddFromTemplate, and store away the
> ProjectItem passed to your OnItemAdded
> handler.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitems.addfromtemplate(v=vs.80).aspx#1

Comment: This creates a new project in na existing solution. I want to create a new project Item (in my case, a Windows Form) in an existing project..

Comment: This surely helps a lot! Well, in the end I'll do what I was avoiding to, but at least I already know it works.. Thanks a lot!