# Adding controls to a form when I only have the reference to it’s EnvDTE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in, envdte, projectitem

I am writing na Add-In for Visual Studio 2010, and I want it to add controls to an existing Form in an existing Project in an existing Solution, and I already have references to all of them.

As I have the reference to the Project Item that represents the file of the form, I want a reference to the Form per se, then I’ll be able to do anything to it (changing properties, and adding controls).

I have tried some approaches, though I must admit I haven’t ran out of tries. But since this is quite an interesting subject, instead of keeping on beating around the bush, I decided to write this question, so it would be faster for me, and would be registered for future similar doubts from anyone else.

Summarizing:

I have:

```
EnvDTE.ProjectItem myPrjItemForm
```

And I want to have:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form myFormObject
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these articles:

[HOWTO: Add a control to a Windows form from a Visual Studio add-in](http://www.mztools.com/Articles/2006/MZ2006016.aspx)

[HOWTO: Manipulating controls of Windows forms from Visual Studio .NET add-ins](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2005/MZ2005001.aspx)

It's VB code, but as far as I can tell, it illustrates the steps you need to perform.